# jQuery, How to print text twice using a for loop?

Tags: jquery

What am I doing wrong here?

---

*I have the following code:*

**HTML:**

```
<div></div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
  console.log('test');
  $('div').text('sometext ');
}
```

**My Output:**

> sometext

**What I expect:**

> sometext sometext

Why does this not print the text to the div twice?

Comment: .text() replaces the contents of the div. :)

Comment: thanks Lily. That was what was throwing me off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `.append()`

**.text replaces the** previous content.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
  console.log('test');
  $('div').append('sometext');
}
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t4hka/)**

**Or**

If you really want to use `text` you can do this

```
var html = '';
for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
  console.log('test');
  html += 'sometext ';
}
$('div').text(html);
```

**[Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/t4hka/1/)**

Store the text in a variable and then use text after the for loop.

Comment: I will keep the variable option in mind. That could be useful for certain situations.

Comment: It's more efficient than adding it each time in a loop, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a createTextNode call instead of just using append, ie this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
  console.log('test');
  $('div').append(document.createTextNode('sometext');
}
```

The append (and appendTo) functions expect HTML, not text. In practice means any special characters (eg < and >) will not get escaped but get processed as HTML. This may or may not be what you intended.

For more info about creating/appending text vs HTML, check the docs and examples for [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) and [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-textString)

Answer (score 0):

```
Print Footer At Bottom Of Page

<div 
media="print"
class="no_screen" 
style=" margin-bottom:0;        
    font-size:10px;
    font-family:arial;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    color:black; "
>Designed By Good People.</div>
```

Working Example Link

jsfiddle.net/ROYALHUNTER/A85QL/